# How to automatically navigate to a screen on start-up

Tags: ios, xcode

When developing an app, if I only want to test one screen, say, the third tab of a tab view, how would I make the app navigate there on start up?

Comment: in your storyboard you set that view to be the starting view.

Comment: it's possible you're looking for this, Ian: that *overall view controller*, which holds the three tabs.  in probably `viewWillAppear`, just have it change to the tab you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good solution is use a UI test to automatically navigate to the correct place in the app. Pausing on a breakpoint at the end of the test leaves the app to be played with manually.

Answer (score 1):

rootViewController of window property in AppDelegate will be the first view controller shown on screen. you can make it by programming or using storyboard

**by programming:**

if NavigationController is the rootViewController of your window, put your own viewController in the first place (index at 0) of NavigationController's viewControllers which is an array. it will be on screen by default.

```
customNavigationController.viewControllers = [yourViewController]
```

or simply set your viewController to the rootViewController to the window property in appDelegate

```
AppDelegate.swift:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarViewController()
        // customViewController will show on screen by default.
        window?.rootViewController = CustomViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

**by interface builder:**

check your viewControlelr's attributes inspector panel, and check "is Initial View Controller" option, then you can see a simple arrow attached to this view controller.

or:

add identifier to your viewController, and fetch it from storyBoard, then set it to the rootViewController of the window object in appDelegate

```
let testController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testController") as! TestController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = testController
```